# Attempt to index number with 'Changed' | Roblox Lua

Tags: lua, roblox

**Hello, I am looking for help to find & solve an error.

Having searched the documentation & finding nothing, I thought this might help some!**

```lua
!1: --# Code | LocalScript --#
!2: function ChangedRO()
!3:    RemoveOpen.Value = OOPetsBase + OOSacrificesBase + OOSettingsBase + OOStatsBase
!4: end
!5: OOPetsBase.Changed:Connect(ChangedRO)
!6: OOSacrificesBase.Changed:Connect(ChangedRO)
!7: SettingsBase.Changed:Connect(ChangedRO)
!8: StatsBase.Changed:Connect(ChangedRO)
```

```lua
--# (Here is the mistake) --#
!5: attempt to index number with 'Changed'
```

**Thank you in advance for your answers!**

Comment: OOPetsBase and OOSacrificesBase are numbers, not NumberValues. Where is the code that defines them?  You may have done something like OOPetsBase = PetsBase.Value rather than OOPetsBase = PetsBase

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are doing `5.Changed`

`Changed` is a method of an instance, so make sure you do it on the instance not on the .Value e.g.

```lua
local intVal = Instance.new("IntValue")
intVal.Changed:Connect(...)
-- And not
local val = intVal.Value
val.Changed:Connect(...)
```

Can you post the the full code next time

Comment: and don't forget to ``:Connect()``!

Comment: yeah right mb, ill fix it